# How to force azure to recognize angular routing?

Tags: angular, azure

I have two pages on my site that are not directly linked to each other:

**ForgotPassword Page:** This page has the user enter their username and then a service gets their email address and emails them a link to reset their password.

**ResetPassword Page:** This URL is sent to the user in email and they click it to reset their password on the page.

Currently they are in the same application.

When I run `ng build` I get the ForgotPassword page built but the ResetPassword page is not. I can directly route to the reset password page through the URL when building locally.

**Note: this all works if I run `ng serve` locally but not on azure**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'reset-password/:userName', component: ResetPasswordComponent },
    ])
  ],
    providers: [
        EmailService,
      ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Update 1**

If I run `ng serve` from a locally built dist folder it also works. So It is something on azure that is hiccoughing.

**Update 2**

After combing the logs I found this:

> D:\home\site\wwwroot\app\reset-password\YourUserId

So it appears azure is not using the angular routing table to route the application. Still working on why.

**Update 3**

I am serving index.html in an app service. I didn't specify a type so I think its a web app by default.

**Update 4**

web.config

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Use internal routing rather than distinct html documents.

Comment: @TheHeadRush what do you mean by that? In my scenario above I cannot allow someone to link directly to the reset password page that would be a security issues.

Comment: if you are adding as normal/external html page that is not a good practice. may you can create component for this page and use it

Comment: Sorry, i somehow got the impression this was all happening after authentication. I should read more thoroughly, i guess. For your use case, i'd create a static html page outside the angular context for the reset page.

Comment: @AmitGolhar I have created a component. There is a route added for the "resetPassword" page. The issue is when you click the link in the email the page doesn't exist on azure as its own page

Comment: Can we see your routing code for the **ForgotPassword** component and the ** ResetPassword** component?

Comment: @narm I have posted the routing code

Comment: What are you using on Azure? App? Blob Storage Hosting? 
Are you always serving the `index.html`?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht see update

Comment: Then please post the web.config.

Comment: Also please notice that because of the nature of Single Page Application like Angular you must have to include some sort of authentication for the request triggering the passwort reset from that page (e.g. a token that is appendend to the requested route and can be used as a bearer for the request.

Comment: @DanielHabenicht There is one I have removed it here

Comment: So you just have to add both files to the routing than? Just add it like the `password-reset` page.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to figure out. Do I need to render both pages or is there a way to force azure to use angular routing so it knows its there?

Comment: Well Angular is a Single Page Application so only the first request is really routed to azure, everything else is client side. That's why azure defaults to serve the `index.html` and angular is than taking over the rest. As your azure app seems to be working you just have to add the component to the angular routes. 
Also a catch all route that redirects to the start-page might be good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201428/discussion-between-robert-and-daniel-habenicht).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The `web.config` you are using is only a part of what it should be. Use this complete sample from [here](https://medium.com/medialesson/best-way-to-host-a-single-page-application-spa-in-microsoft-azure-3e70cbd075c3).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="SPA" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!.*(.js|.css|.png|.jpg|.ico|.svg)).*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/"  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

2.Add all components as route:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
      { path: 'reset-password/:userName', component: ResetPasswordComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
    ])
  ],
    providers: [
        EmailService,
      ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```